# Is it possible to run IIS and Tomcat side by side?

Tags: iis, tomcat

I am required to publish a JSP/Java servlets webapp. Unfortunately IIS does not support such deployments. The server I need to deploy it on already runs IIS and several IIS applications. I don't want to interfere with those applications but it is necessary for them and the new webapp to run on the same server. I tried setting up a proxy to redirect traffic to tomcat, but that broke the other applications.

I was wondering if it's possible to run IIS (accessible through good ol' port 80) and tomcat (running on port 8080); and be able to access both remotely. So far my efforts have been fruitless. Accessing IIS applications yielded no problems, but when I tried to connect to tomcat the browser would just time out. I unblocked port 8080 as well, so I'm sure that is not the issue.

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/iis.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's definitely possible, as long as they run on different ports. If you can access tomcat locally (http://localhost:8080) but not remotely, then it's a firewall issue. Also, if you really wanted you could have iis forward requests to tomcat.

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange IIS and Tomcat in 2 different IP addresses or you can setup reverse-proxy (nginx, lighttpd, mod_proxy, etc.) to port 80 and then set IIS to use port 8080 and for Tomcat port 9090.

Answer (score 0):

Melder, It is perfectly possible to run IIS & Tomcat on same port with Different IPs. One server can have multiple virtual IPs for the same.